# admin page controlling

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new in java and using jsps and servlets and Netbeans IDE for the admin interface 
of my application. there is login page for admin and as he provides correct id and password it moves on next page where there is a link for logout and when admin clicks 
that link he comes back on the login page. Now problem is by clicking the back button 
of browser he moves back to the page from where he was logged out. and of course he 
should not move without providing id and password.i am using session but don't know 
how exactly it would work. how can i control this problem. thanks

code for login.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
   <title> login page </title>     
</head>
<body>
<center>    

   <form  action="Admin_Validation">

      <p>
      Admin ID: <input  type="text" name="AdminID"/>
      </p>
      <p>
      Password: <input type="password" name="Password"/>
      </P>

      <input  type="submit" value="Login" />

   </form>

  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at [Form-Based Authentication with a JSP Page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/6n5sg7cfl/index.html)

Comment: please provide your servlet code